# BlackBerry Library problems. (jre6 + NET_RIM_BLACKBERRY)

Tags: java, blackberry, standards

I'm new in blackberry environement programming, I'm developing an application for this device and there are some probs about libraries that I don't understand.

I have the main project called:

**npoBBerry** - his library is **NET_RIM_BLACKBERRY** (from 4.6.1 version...)
it includes other two projects:

1. **Npo** - his library is standard ***jre6*** (Npo inlcudes NpoCore)
2. **NpoCore** - his library is standard ***jre6***

Compliance was set...
In Java Compiler level is set to 1.4 for all.

Now the problem is that I'm not able to build my project.
4 errors:

1. Error preverifying class ch.yek.npo.model.Advertising
2. Error preverifying class ch.yek.npo.repository.Repository$1
3. Error!: Error: preverifier failed: C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.6.1_4.6.1.27\components\bin\preverify.ex ...
4. Error!: Error: preverifier failed: C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.6.1_4.6.1.27\components\bin\preverify.ex ...

I know that libraries are differents but maybe I'm missing something.

NpoCore represents models, interfaces
Npo just take data from a repository
NpoBBeryy just use this data from Services...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlackBerry applications conform to the J2ME spec, not J2SE.  Therefore, any third-party libraries you use must be specifically for J2ME.  There are some classes between J2ME and J2SE that are similar, but there is also a lot in J2SE that is not in J2ME.